# Dynamically create class with Constructor that calls another Static class method

Tags: c#, static

I'm trying to dynamically create an instance of class `CommandDrawing` which is in another assembly. The `CommandDrawing` class default constructor contains calls to static methods which are inanother another class in the same assembley. The dynamic class is created but when it trys to run the static method call in the constructor it falls over with exception:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   TypeInitializeException`The type initializer for threw an exception.

Do I have to load in both classes and if so how?

I use code below to create the class which I've used successfully before and works when the static method calls are not there:

```
Assembly assemblyCommandDrawing = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\ManifoldInspections.dll");
Type typeCommandDrawing = assemblyCommandDrawing.GetType("InspectionDetails.CommandDrawing");
object cmd = System.Activator.CreateInstance (typeCommandDrawing, new object[] { drawing, DrawingBaseDetail });
```

The `CommandDrawing` default constructor looks like below - note `UtilityMapControl.SetupDrawingTableTemplate` is the static method I'm calling and it falls over here:

```
public CommandDrawing(Manifold.Interop.Drawing p_Drawing, InspectionDetails.DrawingBaseDetail p_ClassDetailTemplate)
{
  this.Drawing = p_Drawing;
  //this.ClassDetailTemplate = p_ClassDetailTemplate.GetType();
  this.ClassDetailTemplate = p_ClassDetailTemplate;
  ManifoldInspections.Utility.UtilityMapControl.SetupDrawingTableTemplate(this.Drawing, p_ClassDetailTemplate);
}
```

Comment: could you provide the code that generates the dynamic class?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?  If so, what is it?  You shouldn't need to explicitly load both classes.

Comment: ivowiblo - sorry I'm dynamically creating an instance of a class rather than the class.

Comment: @ChrisShain Error: {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
Inner Exception : {"The type initializer for 'ManifoldInspections.Utility.UtilityMapControl' threw an exception."}

Comment: @bsheehy01 I'm sure there is yet another inner exception (the one that the type initializer has thrown).

Comment: @Botz3000 InnerException {"The type initializer for 'ManifoldInspections.Utility.UtilityMapControl' threw an exception."} System.Exception {System.TypeInitializationException}

Comment: @bsheehy01 Any more? All the way down? And the messages for each? Those targetinvocation exceptions are sometimes quite deeply nested.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a dependency could not be loaded. If the type initializer uses a type from another Assembly that could happen, because `LoadFile` doesn't resolve dependencies as you might expect. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx):

> `LoadFile` does not load files into the `LoadFrom` context, and does not
>   resolve dependencies using the load path, as the `LoadFrom` method does.

So i suggest using [`LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) instead of `LoadFile`.

Comment: Sorry Botz300 that didnt work either. Failed with the same error